# John is trying to solve this problem for his son . Can you identify the problem?

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

[image: vis]

It is really easy I believe. The answer is wherever you look
Kinda my first attempt. Be kind and thanks for a great community

Comment: rot13(Jura lbh fnl "gur nafjre vf jurerire lbh ybbx", qb lbh zrna gur nafjre gb lbhe dhrfgvba be qb lbh zrna gur nafjre gb gur ceboyrz?)

Comment: rot13(Vf "ybbx Xvaqn" qryvorengryl zvffvat gur "." orgjrra fragraprf? Naq vf "Xvaqn" vafgrnq bs "Xvaq bs" zrnag nf n pyhr?)

Comment: rot13(Gur nafjre vf jurerire lbh ybbx va gur gvgyr, va gur vzntr naq gur grkg
Erfg bs gur jbeqf ner veeryrinag gb gur evqqyr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess at the problem

> What is the maximum number of slices you can get from a circular  ̷c̷a̷k̷e̷  **pie** using five straight cuts?  I notice a Pi symbol at the top right.

Regarding the answer

> You didn't specify that the answer you gave (i.e. 16) is correct so I don't need to check the answer because you only asked for the problem.

**EDIT**

It is really easy I believe.

> On researching this, I find that it refers to the *lazy caterer's sequence*. Of course a lazy person would not care about providing equal pieces - they would do it the ***really easy*** way.

Be kind and thanks for a great community

> I am working on this. I believe it means, "Find a fair way of cutting the pie so everyone is satisfied." I'm guessing I'll find the general answer online somewhere. Not sure I'll be able to derive the answer myself in this lifetime!

The answer is wherever you look

> No idea so far. I think the "answer" may be 16 but maybe the picture resulting from "being kind" will reveal something.

Kinda my first attempt

> You were trying to divide the pie *equally*. Clearly this is an early attempt as you have failed badly.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Could you generalize and more importantly connect all the clues in the puzzle with your answer?

Comment: P.S. Searching online, I've discovered that this is an oldish problem so I may have to research it a bit to get further

Comment: You are in the right direction with the pie thing. Did you read the comment that I wrote with the question?